# Como obtener datos de una pagina haciendo scraping

Tags: c#, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo scraping a una pagina web utilizando C# y un framework HtmlAgilityPack

Me ha ido bien, el problema es cuando quiero obtener datos de un enlace un `<a href`

No se como hacer scraping en un enlace alguna idea usando HtmlAgilityPack

Código

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();

        var doc =
            web.Load(
                "https://dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/facturacion-internet/consultas/publico/xxx-datos2.jspa?ruc=" +
                txtRuc.Text);

        var razonSocialNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"contenido\"]/form/table//td");
        var innerTexts = razonSocialNodes.Select(node => node.InnerText).ToArray();

        txtRazonSocial.Text = innerTexts[0];
        txtNombreComercial.Text = innerTexts[5];
        txtEstado.Text = innerTexts[7];
        txtClaseContribuyente.Text = innerTexts[9];
        txtTipoContribuyente.Text = innerTexts[11];
        txtObligadoContabilidad.Text = innerTexts[13];
        txtActividadEconomica.Text = innerTexts[15];
        txtFechaInicio.Text = innerTexts[17];

        //Aca obtengo los hrefs
        var hrefs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", "")).ToArray();
        // Aca obtengo el href que necesito lo obtengo por posicion pero seria mejor
        // ponerle el nombre de la pagina: ruc-establec.jspa
        var localizar = hrefs[3]; 
    }
```

Acá es donde esta el a href

[image: captura]

En esta imagen necesito navegar hasta donde esta la dirección y tomarla.
[image: dirección]

Me parecio que con este código se podía hacer

```
static void Main()
{
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("test.html");
    var anchor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@href, 'url-a')]");
    if (anchor != null)
    {
        var id = anchor.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::td/a");
        if (id != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id.InnerHtml);
            var img = id.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::td/a");
            if (img != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(img.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias poner el codigo que estas usando para parsear el html, porque la clave esta en como defines el selector

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya lo actualice.

Comment: pero en la imagen del html que muestras no veo ningun tag "a" que represente un link, el dato al que haces referencia esta sobre el nodo "td"

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ya lo actualice primera imagen es el a href y la sengundo imagen es cuando estoy dentro del segundo enlace

Comment: pero si son dos html diferentes la seleccion con la libreria HtmlAgilityPack es distinta, no veo en que aplica la imagen de la tabla si necesitas acceder al dato del link, del cual no veo cual es el contexto del html mas alla de div que lo contiene

Comment: Es una url la cual tiene secciones al hacer click dirige a otra pagina

Comment: Lo he solucionado con un control webwrose si no que no me gusta, pero veo que es la única solución.

Comment: si necesitabas navegar podrias usar el WebClient o HttpClient una vez que tenias la url, y asi obtener el html para parsearlo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini En la primera pagina tomo los datos relevantes con HtmlAgilityPack, y solo para obtener la dirección tenía que navegar pero lo he descartado tomar la dirección ya que tengo que ir a un enlace esperar que cargue la pagina y tomar el dato, lo hace lento.

Comment: @PedroÁvila sería de ayuda a la comunidad si respondes y aceptas tu propia respuesta. Saludos.